# OllyDBG source view / C++ DLL

Tags: c++, dll, ollydbg

i wrote my DLL in C++, compiled in Releasemode, and i find out, that i can view the complete source, ex. main.cpp etc ( full source code) in ollydbg->view->sourcfiles.

what the hell did i wrong? this should not be happen.
how to prevent that?
thanks in advance.

[image: olly dbg view]

Comment: Does this show the source code on a different computer? I mean one that does not have your source code.

Comment: You obviously have .pdb file in the same directory as executable.

Comment: yes, thats possible, on others PC it dont show up thanks, but another question, whats the best way to protect my dll without decrypting, work with dll, encrypt it again?

Comment: The PDB file contains the information about which parts of the DLL come from which source code files, lines, etc. The DLL alone does not contain this information. Without both the PDB and source files, it is not possible to see your code in this simple way.